# batch file with inline powershell script that contains variables

Tags: powershell, batch-file, quoting

Attempting to execute a PowerShell script from within a bat script. The PowerShell script works fine when executed within PowerShell, but not when executed from within cmd.

```
@echo off

set hostName=10.0.0.1
set logfile=C:\github\temp\log_pings\Log_%hostName%.log
echo Network Loging Running %hostName%...
echo Ping Log %hostName% > %logfile%

powershell "ping.exe -t %hostName% | Foreach{ ""{0} - {1}"" -f (Get-Date) ,$_ }" >> %logfile%
```

My reason for using a batch script is ease of executing for users from an explorer window.

Comment: Change `""{0} - {1}""` to `'{0} - {1}'`

Comment: @Daniel That answer you linked didn't really answer my question. I had seen it but it was too broad

Comment: Sorry about that.  The linked post does apply though.  It says that you can escape the `"` in the powershell command with `\"` which also works `\"{0} - {1}\"`.  2nd part is basically same as what I recommended, to avoid double quotes and replace with single quotes

Comment: Note that if you used _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, (`pwsh -c "..."`), your command would work as-is, but, strangely, _Windows PowerShell_ (`powershell.exe`)  doesn't accept `""` as  escaped `"`. `\"` works in both PowerShell editions and effectively on all platforms, but from `cmd.exe` it can break in certain situations, due to `cmd.exe`'s limitations; e.g. `powershell -c "'The King of \"Rock & Roll\".'"`. In that case, use `""` with `pwsh`, and `"^""` (sic) with `powershell.exe`. It's not always an option, but embedded _single_-quoting , as proposed by @Daniel, is an easy workaround.

Comment: @mklement0 it did seem inconsistent when I was trying out different options. The `\"` nor did the `""` which is what got me confused

Comment: @pcnate, unless you run into the `cmd.exe`-side problems I mentioned, `\"` should work, however, in both editions.